# Resolving ORA-00937: not a single-group group function

Tags: sql, oracle

I was solving a question where

Table: `Activity`

```
+--------------+---------+
| Column Name  | Type    |
+--------------+---------+
| player_id    | int     |
| device_id    | int     |
| event_date   | date    |
| games_played | int     |
+--------------+---------+
```

`(player_id, event_date)` is the primary key of this table. This table shows the activity of players of some games.

Each row is a record of a player who logged in and played a number of games (possibly 0) before logging out on someday using some device.

Write a SQL query to report the fraction of players that logged in again on the day after the day they first logged in, rounded to 2 decimal places. In other words, you need to count the number of players that logged in for at least two consecutive days starting from their first login date, then divide that number by the total number of players. The query result format is in the following example.

Input:

`Activity` table:

```
+-----------+-----------+------------+--------------+
| player_id | device_id | event_date | games_played |
+-----------+-----------+------------+--------------+
| 1         | 2         | 2016-03-01 | 5            |
| 1         | 2         | 2016-03-02 | 6            |
| 2         | 3         | 2017-06-25 | 1            |
| 3         | 1         | 2016-03-02 | 0            |
| 3         | 4         | 2018-07-03 | 5            |
+-----------+-----------+------------+--------------+
```

Output:

```
+-----------+
| fraction  |
+-----------+
| 0.33      |
+-----------+
```

Explanation:

Only the player with id 1 logged back in after the first day he had logged in so the answer is 1/3 = 0.33

I wrote this for the question:

```
select 
    round(count(a1.player_id) / (select count(distinct player_id) as cnt from activity a3), 2)
from
    (select 
         activity.*, 
         row_number() over (partition by player_id order by event_date) as rn
     from 
         activity) a1 
join 
    activity a2 on a1.rn = 1 
                and a2.event_date - a1.event_date = 1 
                and a1.player_id = a2.player_id;
```

But I am getting the following error:

> ERROR at line 32:
> ORA-00937: not a single-group group function

EDIT:

I actually solved this using this:

```
with retained as (
  select count(*) as ret
  from
  (
      select activity.*, row_number() over(partition by player_id order by event_date) as rn
      from activity
  ) a1 join activity a2
  on
  a1.rn = 1 and
  a2.event_date - a1.event_date = 1 and
  a1.player_id = a2.player_id
),
total as (
  select count(distinct player_id) as cnt
  from activity
)
select distinct round(ret/cnt, 2) as fraction from retained, total;
;
```

The only difference from my original solution is that I refactored using separate statements. But I still am not sure why my original was wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Oracle 12, you can use `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` to perform row-by-row pattern matching and look for when a player's second login is the day after the first login and then use conditional aggregation to find the fraction:

```sql
SELECT ROUND(COUNT(day2)/COUNT(*), 2) AS fraction
FROM   activity
MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
  PARTITION BY player_id
  ORDER     BY event_date
  MEASURES
    day2.event_date AS day2
  PATTERN ( ^ day1 day2? )
  DEFINE
    day2 AS day2.event_date = day1.event_date + 1
)
```

or, if you want to use analytic functions then:

```sql
SELECT ROUND(
         COUNT(CASE WHEN event_date = min_date + 1 THEN player_id END)
         / COUNT(CASE WHEN event_date = min_date THEN player_id END),
         2
       ) AS fraction
FROM   (
  SELECT player_id,
         event_date,
         MIN(event_date) OVER (PARTITION BY player_id) AS min_date
  FROM   activity
)
```

Which, for the sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE activity (player_id, device_id, event_date, games_played) AS
  SELECT 1, 2, DATE '2016-03-01', 5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 2, DATE '2016-03-02', 6 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 3, DATE '2017-06-25', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 1, DATE '2016-03-02', 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 4, DATE '2018-07-03', 5 FROM DUAL;
```

Both output:

| FRACTION |
| --- |
| .33 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ZYlDWXh4)

Comment: Great solutions, especially the second one. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try using the window function `count()` :

```
select distinct round(count(a2.player_id) over() / count_players, 2) as fraction
from
    (select 
         activity.*, 
         row_number() over (partition by player_id order by event_date) as rn,
         count(distinct PLAYER_ID) over () as count_players
     from 
         activity
    ) a1 
left join 
    activity a2 on a1.rn = 1 
                and a2.event_date - a1.event_date = 1 
                and a1.player_id = a2.player_id;
```

Using `left join` instead of `join` will help to return the expected result when the condition not matched at any player .

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/W3Ul-QG_)

Comment: But, count(*) I have been using without Group by too. Like in my code when I used count(*) instead of all the fraction. It is working fine. Then why would the error occur when I divide it by a constant?

Comment: Actually your code gives incorrect output for this input. Like it repeats 1 two time.  | player_id | device_id | event_date | games_played |
| --------- | --------- | ---------- | ------------ |
| 1         | 2         | 2016-03-01 | 5            |
| 1         | 2         | 2016-03-02 | 1            |
| 3         | 1         | 2016-01-02 | 10           |
| 3         | 4         | 2016-01-03 | 15           |

Comment: The issue is that your query is trying to perform two levels of aggregation at once

Comment: I have made an edit, can you have a look https://dbfiddle.uk/_IpN35tB

Comment: Actually, it is still failing in this case | player_id | device_id | event_date | games_played |
| --------- | --------- | ---------- | ------------ |
| 1         | 8         | 1970-01-01 | 0            |
| 2         | 9         | 1970-01-01 | 0            |

Comment: Yes, its zero....

Comment: I have made an edit, can you check

Comment: This code is running in my system without any errors. But, Leetcode doesn't seem to accept the solution, and throws an runtime error. Could you check once  leetcode.com/problems/game-play-analysis-iv

Comment: I have edited my question with my solution which works. Can you elaborate on why my original solution didn't work? Can you elaborate on the two levels of aggregation thing.

Answer (score 1):

You could use analytic functions ( Count() Over() and Lead() Over() ) to get both - the total number of players and day difference to see if the loggings were on consecutive days (DAY_DIFF = 1).
**UPDATED:**

```sql
WITH         --  Sample data
    activity AS
        (   Select 1 "PLAYER_ID", 2 "DEVICE_ID", To_Date('2016-03-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd') "EVENT_DATE", 5 "GAMES_PLAYED" From Dual Union All
            Select 1 "PLAYER_ID", 2 "DEVICE_ID", To_Date('2016-03-02', 'yyyy-mm-dd') "EVENT_DATE", 6 "GAMES_PLAYED" From Dual Union All
            Select 2 "PLAYER_ID", 3 "DEVICE_ID", To_Date('2017-06-25', 'yyyy-mm-dd') "EVENT_DATE", 1 "GAMES_PLAYED" From Dual Union All
            Select 3 "PLAYER_ID", 1 "DEVICE_ID", To_Date('2016-03-02', 'yyyy-mm-dd') "EVENT_DATE", 0 "GAMES_PLAYED" From Dual Union All
            Select 3 "PLAYER_ID", 4 "DEVICE_ID", To_Date('2018-07-03', 'yyyy-mm-dd') "EVENT_DATE", 5 "GAMES_PLAYED" From Dual 
        )
--  Main SQL
Select 
    Round(Count(DISTINCT PLAYER_ID) / Max(TOTAL_PLAYERS), 2) "fraction"
From
    (
        Select 
          PLAYER_ID, 
          EVENT_DATE,
          Sum(1) OVER(Partition By PLAYER_ID Order By PLAYER_ID, EVENT_DATE) "LOGGING_NO",
          Count(DISTINCT PLAYER_ID) OVER() "TOTAL_PLAYERS",
          Nvl(LEAD(EVENT_DATE) OVER(Partition By PLAYER_ID Order By PLAYER_ID, EVENT_DATE) - EVENT_DATE, 0) "DAY_DIFF"
        From
          activity
    )
Where DAY_DIFF = 1 And LOGGING_NO = 1
--
--
  fraction
----------
       .33
```

Added one more analytic column in inner query to get first (and else) loggings.
The main job has been done with inner query which results as:

```sql
 PLAYER_ID EVENT_DAT LOGGING_NO TOTAL_PLAYERS   DAY_DIFF
---------- --------- ---------- ------------- ----------
         1 01-MAR-16          1             3          1
         1 02-MAR-16          2             3          0
         2 25-JUN-17          1             3          0
         3 02-MAR-16          1             3        853
         3 03-JUL-18          2             3          0
```

The outer select just counts distinct players with dayly consecutive loggings and divides it with total number of players.
Well, it works there - they just weren't satisfied with column name "RESULT" for some reason. Changed it to "fraction" and here it is:
[image]

Comment: This is giving wrong answers for a test case. The test case is quite big. So, can you kindly check from this link https://leetcode.com/problems/game-play-analysis-iv/

Comment: I have added my updated solution, which I submitted here https://leetcode.com/problems/game-play-analysis-iv/submissions/934810223/. Can you explain why my original solution didn't work, and is there any benefits to using count() over()?

Comment: @VedantaMohapatra please try the updated code. Didn't notice the first logging condition. The code now checks if player logged 1 day after the very first logging.

Comment: Great solution, thanks. Learnt a few things.